# SSRS Dataset depending on other dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I have a problem with setting up a report. I am a beginner with SSRS.

I have two datasets:

A dataset from an XML source:

Object with Name, Number and Location.
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LtXl.png)

A dataset from a stored procedure with a Name and Number parameter that returns a code depending on the first dataset.
[return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMtnj.png)

In the report I have a group per Location and I must display a string that contains (Name, Number, Code) for each Object separated by ";"

This must give me all the objects in a location.

For Location A : (A,1,1234);(B,2,2345);(C,3,3456)

For Location B : (A,1,1234)

For Location C : (B,2,3456)

So I tried to use the expression below but I don't know how to return the code:

```
Join(LookupSet(Fields!Location.Value,Fields!Location.Value,Fields!Name.Value &"," & Fields!Number.Value &"," & <the code> , "Object"),";")
```

I don't know how to add a call to the second dataset which takes parameters from the first dataset. How to build the string wanted?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you show your datastet I mean exactly what your data is coming from two tables (sources). Once We have a data it won't be difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: I make some edits with data sample. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a sub-report in a group by (name, number) that has the name and number as parameters. My dataset to retrieve the code works well.
But now I can't retrieve the strings obtained in the parent group.
So I have this:

Location A

(A,1,1234)

(B,2,2345)

(C,3,3456)

Location B

(A,1,1234)

Location C

(B,2,2345)

While I want the data for each location in the same field like this:

For Location A : (A,1,1234);(B,2,2345);(C,3,3456)

For Location B : (A,1,1234)

For Location C : (B,2,3456)

Anyone know how could I do that?